# Scaling applications in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, scaling, screen-resolution, screen-size

I've written an application for Windows 8.1, which works on the full screen (is not scrollable). I tried to use theme resources, in belief, that these are prepared for different phones separately; to my surprise, sizes of fonts on much smaller phone than mine (I own Lumia 1320) are exactly the same, resulting in cut button labels.

The layout is done on `Grid`s, so it will scale up or down to size of screen; a few icons are either `SymbolIcon`s or `Path`s, so they will scale as well, but how should I choose sizes of fonts? I've read a few documents on MSDN pages, but they doesn't mention how to prepare application for scaling to different screen sizes and resolutions from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

You can try using this for texts:

```
IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True"
```

### Previous answer:

You could use a Viewbox which is a quick solution that scales the entire content inside the element. This would be a XAML approach

```
<ViewBox>
    <!-- XAML children go here -->
</ViewBox>
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox

You can also pull the screen resolution from the current window and then add predefined resources accordingly:

```
// Get your style
Style style = (Style)mainWindow.FindResource("MyStyleResource1"); 
var width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
if (width < ...)
    style = (Style)mainWindow.FindResource("MyStyleResourceNarrow");
myXAMLElement.Style = style;
```

As most of the elements usually scale easily with their sourrounding containers you will only need that for a couple of textblocks, I guess.